# Get current item number in ColorBox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

When you open ColorBox popup for group of items by default it shows what is current number of item in whole group and what is the total number of items. 
How to get these values client side?

Comment: Have you tried using $(this) ?

Comment: Sure, and also $.colorbox.element() as written on official doc.

Comment: When you say current number where is this stored in the structure of the HTML?

Comment: I think it's stored in memory only. If I knew where it is, it looked quite stupid from to ask it)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your configuration, you can (usually) get the index number of the currently displayed image (starting from 0) as follows:

```
var currentImageNumber = $.colorbox.element().index();
```

To get the number of images currently displayed in your colorbox (supposing you are displaying a **group** of images, like in the [examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) in the Colorbox website), you can use the following sentence:

```
var imagesGroupLength = $.colorbox.element().siblings().length + 1;
```

Remember to store (cache) these values somewhere to reduce computation time.

Comment: the imagesGroupLength was not accurate when adding 1 for some reason

Comment: `$.colorbox.element().index()` is always returning 1 for `jquery-colorbox@1.6.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is funny - these values (total number in collection, instance number of the item currently shown) are **already** client-side - unless you are executing the ColorBox plugin on a server.

The ideas below are based on the first example used in the ColorBox website, a very vanilla, easy case. Your case may differ.

GETTING THE COLLECTION SIZE

Easily done as follows, where ".group1" is the collection of assets and console.log included as a verification.

```
var a = $('.group1').length;
console.log(a);
```

GETTING THE NUMBER OF THE DISPLAYED INSTANCE

Easily done as follows, with the same test setup as used in the prior case.

```
$('.group1').on( 'click', function () {
  var h = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(h);
});
```

Var "h" contains an href, you would then iterate through the collection to find the entry with that href.

Note that there are other (better!) ways to do this. For example, if each item in the collection has an ID, then you can simple say

```
var h = this.id
```

Note that this is all done outside the plugin. To make it supercool, just fork the plugin and implement the changes after studying the use of the elements **current** and **index**.

Answer (score 0):

I use `jquery-colorbox@1.6.4` with this setup (see the `a-image` usage):

```
<ul class="image-set">
  <li>
    <img src="img url here">
    <a href="img url here too" class="d-none a-image" title="img name"></a>
  </li>
  ... other <li> items ...
</ul>
```

I have this code getting the current colorbox current item number:

```
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', () => {
    $.colorbox.close();
    console.log('current colorbox item number:\n', $('.a-image').index($.colorbox.element()));
});
```

My answer is (I point exactly the working code getting the current item number):

```
$('.a-image').index($.colorbox.element())
```

where `$('.a-image')` is the one used to initialize colorbox as e.g. for my situation:

```
this.colorbox = $('.a-image').colorbox({
  rel: 'a-image', open: false, maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '100%',
  slideshow: true, slideshowAuto: false, slideshowSpeed: 2000,
});
```